# Searching in CardDAV

Tags: webdav, carddav, sabredav

I want to write a little LDAP 2 CardDav Gateway, which gets a request (from a Desktop Phone/PBX) on it's LDAP side and converts it to a CardDAV request.

So for I used raw HTTP/XML requests and was able to:

- Query the base directory */kdav/addressbooks/* with `PROPFIND` and `depth: 1`
- for results with `<d:resourcetype><d:collection>` repeat the query recursivly
- for results with `<d:resourcetype><card:addressbook>` add them to the addressbook list
- after the recursion is done a `REPORT` query with `<card:addressbook-query><card:address-data><card:prop name="TEL"><card:prop name="N"></card:address-data>` over the addreesbook list

Now this gives me currently the possibility to get all contacts and create a phonebook.xml, which can be fetched by my phones.

Unfortunatly I was unable to restrict the `PROPFIND` to only return results of `<d:resourcetype><d:collection>` or `<d:resourcetype><card:addressbook>`. This is problematic, as I can have nested addressbooks, which return all children on `PROPFIND`, in the worst case this means I query an addressbook, which has no nested address books, but 500 contacts, so I get 500 results back which I completely filter out on client side.

Any ideas on how to solve that more efficient?

Also here is an example of a response I currently get, which makes me assume that the addressbooks are nested. The server is [Kopano](https://kopano.com/) and either I'm misinterpreting nested address books or it breaks the specification.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<d:multistatus
    xmlns:d="DAV:"
    xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns"
    xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav"
    xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"
    xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
    <d:response>
        <d:href>/kdav/addressbooks/public/</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection/>
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>/kdav/addressbooks/public/sdfsf/</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection/>
                    <card:addressbook/>
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>/kdav/addressbooks/public/Test/</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection/>
                    <card:addressbook/>
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

Comment: If the server supports RFC 5323, you could try the SEARCH method.

Comment: @JulianReschke I guess from the sabre/dav Standards Support https://sabre.io/dav/standards-support that would be an NO.

Comment: CardDAV doesn't support nested addressbooks, to quote the RFC: "Address book collections MUST only contain address object resources and collections that are not address book collections"

Comment: @hnh I added a example response, don't know If I'm just an idiot or if the spec is broken there.

Comment: The response looks fine to me. `public` is the address book home (it isn't an AB itself) and there are two address books in there (`sdfsf` and `Test`).

Comment: Sounds like your `public` contains contacts? This isn't strictly forbidden, but it isn't marked as an AB, so what would be the point? 
To filter such a collection, you'd need SEARCH support, as mentioned by Julian.

Comment: @hnh It's actually the /kdav/addressbooks/public/Test/ folder I'm talking about, since it has two resourcetypes.

Comment: A DAV collection can have multiple resource types, e.g. it could also be a CalDAV collection at the same time! That it has DAV:collection and CD:addressbook is proper and expected (it supports all DAV:collection operations, and in addition it supports CardDAV queries).
Maybe rephrase your original question, it is unclear to me what exactly you want given the discussion :-) You didn't show nested ABs yet (and as mentioned such are forbidden in CardDAV (and CalDAV).